# What does this question involving classes of sets mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is this question asking?

"Which of the following classes of sets are closed under each of the following operations: union, intersection, power set operation?" An example class given is the class of all finite sets.

I guess I am asking for the meaning of classes of sets, closed classes, and what the operations do to these classes.

Comment: Are you confused about what a class of sets is, or about what "closed" means, or about what these operators are?

Comment: Actually, all of those. Would it have been better to ask these separately?..

Comment: I don't think you have to ask them separately. I just wanted clarification about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Added after clarification of the question:** In this context the term *class* of sets is being used very informally. You should think of it simply as some well-defined collection of sets, in the sense that it’s possible to decide unambiguously whether a set belongs to the collection or not. For instance, once you have a definition of *finite set*, it’s possible in principle to determine whether any given set is finite and hence whether it belongs to the class of finite sets or not.
>
> The operations don’t do anything to the classes: they are operations on the **members** of the classes, and we’re interested in whether the results of those operations are themselves always members of the same class.

When we say that a collection $\mathscr{C}$ of sets is closed under some operation, we just mean that when you apply that operation to members of $\mathscr{C}$, you always get a member of $\mathscr{C}$. Suppose, for instance, that $\mathscr{C}$ is the class of all finite sets. If $A,B\in\mathscr{C}$, is it true that $A\cup B\in\mathscr{C}$? Yes: the union of two finite sets is finite. Therefore $\mathscr{C}$ is *closed under* $\cup$. Is it true that $A\cap B\in\mathscr{C}$? Again, yes: the intersection of two finite sets is finite, so $\mathscr{C}$ is *closed under* $\cap$. Finally, is it true that $\wp(A)\in\mathscr{C}$? Once again the answer is yes: a finite set has only finitely many subsets, so its power set is again finite, and $\mathscr{C}$ is *closed under* $\wp$. (In fact if $A$ has $n$ members, $\wp(A)$ has $2^n$ members.)

Suppose now that $\mathscr{C}$ is the class of all infinite sets. Then $\mathscr{C}$ is closed under union and power set (why?), but not under intersection: the set of positive integers and the set of negative integers are infinite sets whose intersection is not infinite. (It’s as far from infinite as you can get!)

Comment: What is the more elegant/formal definition of class?

Comment: @Sigur: The term is being used informally here, so the question doesn’t really apply.

Comment: I agree. It was only to get a reference here, instead of make another question. It is not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Does the union operation on a class  = {{set1},{set2},{set3},...} also return the union of all the sets in the class, or does it only return the union of pairs of sets like in your example?

Comment: @James: Unless otherwise specified, it’s understood to be the binary union operation: $\mathscr{C}$ is closed under union if $A\cap B\in\mathscr{C}$ whenever $A,B\in\mathscr{C}$. No claim is being made about unions of more than two sets from the class. (One can then prove by induction that for any positive integer $n$, $A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_n\in\mathscr{C}$ whenever $A_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathscr{C}$, but one cannot conclude the class is closed under taking unions of infinitely many of its members.)

Comment: Okay, that is what I gathered from your answer.